# repeat printf to display an integer

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
int x = 1;
for (x; x<=4; x++)
    printf("%0*d\n",x,0);
```

it outputs

```
0
00
000
0000
```

How do I make the output go

```
1
22
333
4444
```

I've tried:

```
printf("%x*d\n",x,0);
```

and

```
printf("%" + x + "*d\n",x,0);
```

but it does not work. I wanted to use only one for loop if possible.

Comment: You should read a tutorial on `printf` format strings... and on c++ in general. You are trying to mix many things, that in c++ don't work like you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to actually print `x` `x` times:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 4; ++x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        printf("%d", x);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Or, since this is C++:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 4; ++x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        std::cout << x;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) constructor that makes multiple copies of the same char (#2 in the reference):

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 4; ++x) {
    std::cout << std::string(x, x + '0') << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use only 1 for loop if possible

Answer (score 7):

If you are able to use C++ streams, you could use the `fill` method to set the character of the padding and use the `setw` modifier from `<iomanip>` to set the padding of the next output operation.

```
for(int x = 1 ; x <= 4; x++)
{
    char prev = std::cout.fill(x + '0');
    std::cout << std::setw(x) << x << std::endl;
    std::cout.fill(prev);
}
```

Notice this works only for numbers up to 9, I assume that's a non issue for you.

Comment: Why not just [`std::setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill)?

Comment: @Barry I used the method because it returns the previous fill character so that I would be able to restore it later.